# How to limit the display of a Searched Node in a JTree to itself and its parents (other nodes will be excluded in the display)?

Tags: java, user-interface, search, nodes, jtree

I want to display the searched node and its parents only. I wanted to exclude the unrelated nodes. My code only does search and display but it does not filter out the other nodes. They are still in the display.

What approach can be done to do this? You can get what I mean by going the Eclipse's Run Configurations' Search function. It only displays what is searched and it's "parents".
[image]

Thank you so much for your input . I am trapped here for days . =(

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Enumeration;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel;
import javax.swing.tree.MutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.TreePath;

public class SearchTree extends JFrame {

    private DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Root");

    private DefaultTreeModel model = new DefaultTreeModel(root);

    private JTree tree = new JTree(model);

    private JButton searchButton = new JButton("Search Node");

    private JTextField searchText;

    public SearchTree() {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode n1 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Sample 1");
        n1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("2nd level: Child l"));
        n1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Search Me"));
        n1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Bob"));

        DefaultMutableTreeNode n2 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Find me");
        n2.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("2nd level: Child 2"));
        n2.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Peter"));
        n2.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Lily"));

        DefaultMutableTreeNode n3 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Explore me");
        n3.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("2nd level: Child 3"));
        n3.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Rome"));
        n3.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Italy"));

        root.add(n1);
        root.add(n2);
        root.add(n3);

        tree.setEditable(true);
        tree.setSelectionRow(0);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(tree);
        getContentPane().add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel searchPanel = new JPanel();
        searchPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());

        searchText = new JTextField(10);
        searchPanel.add(searchText);

        searchButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                DefaultMutableTreeNode node = searchNode(searchText.getText());
                if (node != null) {
                    TreeNode[] nodes = model.getPathToRoot(node);
                    TreePath path = new TreePath(nodes);
                    tree.scrollPathToVisible(path);
                    tree.setSelectionPath(path);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Node with string "
                            + searchText.getText() + " not found");
                }
            }
        });
        searchPanel.add(searchButton);

        getContentPane().add(searchPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        setSize(700, 400);
        setVisible(true);

    }

    public DefaultMutableTreeNode searchNode(String nodeStr) {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode node = null;
        Enumeration e = root.breadthFirstEnumeration();
        while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
            node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) e.nextElement();
            if (nodeStr.equals(node.getUserObject().toString())) {
                return node;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void removeNode(DefaultMutableTreeNode selNode) {
        if (selNode == null) {
            return;
        }
        MutableTreeNode parent = (MutableTreeNode) (selNode.getParent());
        if (parent == null) {
            return;
        }
        MutableTreeNode toBeSelNode = getSibling(selNode);
        if (toBeSelNode == null) {
            toBeSelNode = parent;
        }
        TreeNode[] nodes = model.getPathToRoot(toBeSelNode);
        TreePath path = new TreePath(nodes);
        tree.scrollPathToVisible(path);
        tree.setSelectionPath(path);
        model.removeNodeFromParent(selNode);
    }

    private MutableTreeNode getSibling(DefaultMutableTreeNode selNode) {
        MutableTreeNode sibling = (MutableTreeNode) selNode
                .getPreviousSibling();
        if (sibling == null) {
            sibling = (MutableTreeNode) selNode.getNextSibling();
        }
        return sibling;
    }

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        SearchTree st = new SearchTree();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's what you were looking for:

**Edit 4:**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel;
import javax.swing.tree.MutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.TreePath;

public class SearchTree extends JFrame {

    private final DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Root");
    private final DefaultTreeModel model = new DefaultTreeModel(root);
    private final JTree tree = new JTree(model);
    private final JLabel searchLabel = new JLabel("Enter Node to be searched");
    private final JTextField searchText;
    private final ArrayList<DefaultMutableTreeNode> initNodes = new ArrayList<>();

    public SearchTree() {

        DefaultMutableTreeNode n1 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Sample 1");
        n1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("2nd level: Child l"));
        n1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Search Me"));
        n1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Bob"));

        DefaultMutableTreeNode n2 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Find me");
        n2.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("2nd level: Child 2"));
        n2.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Peter"));
        n2.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Lily"));

        DefaultMutableTreeNode n3 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Explore me");
        n3.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Search Me Please"));
        n3.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Rome"));
        n3.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Italy"));

        initNodes.add(n1);
        initNodes.add(n2);
        initNodes.add(n3);

        root.add(n1);
        root.add(n2);
        root.add(n3);

        tree.setEditable(true);
        tree.setSelectionRow(0);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(tree);
        getContentPane().add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel searchPanel = new JPanel();
        searchPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());

        searchText = new JTextField(20);
        searchText.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new SearchListener());
        searchPanel.add(searchText);

        searchPanel.add(searchLabel);

        getContentPane().add(searchPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        setSize(700, 400);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void removeNode(DefaultMutableTreeNode selNode) {
        if (selNode == null) {
            return;
        }
        MutableTreeNode parent = (MutableTreeNode) (selNode.getParent());
        if (parent == null) {
            return;
        }
        MutableTreeNode toBeSelNode = getSibling(selNode);
        if (toBeSelNode == null) {
            toBeSelNode = parent;
        }
        TreeNode[] nodes = model.getPathToRoot(toBeSelNode);
        TreePath path = new TreePath(nodes);
        tree.scrollPathToVisible(path);
        tree.setSelectionPath(path);
        model.removeNodeFromParent(selNode);
        initNodes.remove(selNode);
    }

    private MutableTreeNode getSibling(DefaultMutableTreeNode selNode) {
        MutableTreeNode sibling = (MutableTreeNode) selNode
                .getPreviousSibling();
        if (sibling == null) {
            sibling = (MutableTreeNode) selNode.getNextSibling();
        }
        return sibling;
    }

    private class SearchListener implements DocumentListener {

        boolean expandIt = false;

        @Override
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            documentListener();
        }

        @Override
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            documentListener();
        }

        @Override
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            documentListener();
        }

        private void documentListener() {
            ArrayList<DefaultMutableTreeNode> list = searchNode(searchText.getText());
            root.removeAllChildren();
            for (DefaultMutableTreeNode mtn : list) {
                root.add(mtn);
            }

            model.reload(root);
            if (expandIt) {
                for (int i = 0; i < tree.getRowCount(); i++) {
                    tree.expandRow(i);
                }
            }

        }

        public ArrayList<DefaultMutableTreeNode> searchNode(String nodeStr) {
            if (nodeStr == null || nodeStr.isEmpty()) {
                expandIt = false;
                return initNodes;
            }
            expandIt = true;
            ArrayList<DefaultMutableTreeNode> list = new ArrayList<>();
            for (DefaultMutableTreeNode mtn : initNodes) {
                if (checkText(mtn, nodeStr)) {
                    list.add(mtn);
                    continue;
                }
                DefaultMutableTreeNode parent = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) mtn.clone();
                for (int i = 0; i < mtn.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    DefaultMutableTreeNode child = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) mtn.getChildAt(i);
                    if (checkText(child, nodeStr)) {
                        parent.add((DefaultMutableTreeNode) child.clone());
                    }
                }
                if (parent.getChildCount() > 0) {
                    list.add(parent);
                }
            }
            return list;
        }

        public boolean checkText(DefaultMutableTreeNode node, String text) {
            return node.getUserObject().toString().toLowerCase().startsWith(text.toLowerCase());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        SearchTree st = new SearchTree();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man but it is not displaying the node itself. It is only displaying the parent node.

Comment: Is there a way that it still shows their parent nodes?

Comment: The searched node disappeared again. You just have to put your 2nd and 3rd revision together and that will be the answer =)

Comment: it's not disappeared, it's just inside its parent, how do you want to show its parent and leave it outside of it ?

Comment: It will show a collapsed parent and the searched node is in it. Is it possible?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77358/discussion-between-doublema-and-philip-morris).

Comment: If you have time can you check on this also? Thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30112070/restricting-the-addition-of-nodes-of-a-jtree-except-for-the-1st-level-child